# Backing up sf data in external DB

Tags: data-export, database, backup

Hi I need to back up my sf org data into my local database. I am looking out for tools or any best practices to this at specific time intervals or regular time intervals. Can any one suggest what would be the best way to go about it.

I am not looking for the data export wizard, I know it exists, but I need to sync the data with my external dB directly. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you able to provide any more details around what technologies you're using? What data you are looking to backup? How frequently you're looking to back up?

Comment: There are a lot of options out there that you can find with a simple Google search: https://www.google.com/?q=salesforce+database+sync. As it stands, this question will likely be closed unless you add details and more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sfdc_ninja said, demand tools is a good tool. I think this should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

While there are a lot of tools out there with some fancy bells and whistles, you can do a simple data export just by using the standard export Data functionality.  It allows you to schedule the export.

**Setup -> Data Management -> Export Data -> Click 'Schedule Export' button**

[image]

The frequency in which you can export is based on your edition.  From the documentation

> Weekly export available in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited
>   Editions Monthly export available in: All editions, except for
>   Database.com

Check out the documentation here

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_exportdata.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I am looking for data sync up to another database directly and not want them as csv files.

Comment: ahhhh, then you will likely need to look into some 3rd party tools.  DemandTools by CRMFusion is one that I have used before and it worked ok.  [http://crmfusion.com/demandtools/]

Comment: great thanks., it says it can do back ups, so it should be with another database right?

Comment: You can post that as an answer

Comment: I have set it up to export to a onsite SQL database before so I know it can do that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options out there that can do this the best I've found out there are Dell Boomi, Sesame Software Relational Junction, and Infomatica Data Replication and all three are quite simple to use and pretty aggressive.

Happy Data Moving !!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh and if you're good with building a SSIS package you could a add on from pragmatic works fairly cheaply to move data between Salesforce and SQL.  But i wouldn't recommend it for moving data over 100k rows.